# Cannot send or receive emails

Tags: gmail

I am receiving this message:

> Technical details of permanent failure:
> Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the relay ams22.stablehost.com [107.6.169.58].
>
> The error that the other server returned was:
> 550-Verification failed for `<info@aurorabootcamp.com>`
> 550-Mailbox quota exceeded
> 550 Sender verify failed

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a Gmail problem. This is, if anything, an email administration problem.

"Mailbox quota exceeded" is just what it sounds like. The mailbox has received more email than it is configured to accept.

"Sender verify failed" sounds like it couldn't verify your identity. Gmail doesn't like email sent through SMTP gateways.

We'd need more information for a more comprehensive answer.